# Pandas - Using a list of values to create a smaller frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of values that are found in a large pandas dataframe:

```
value_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 54]
```

Example DataFrame `df` is below:

```
   column x
0  1      3
1  4      6
2  5      8
3  6      19
4  8      21
5  12     97
6  54     102
```

I would like to create a subset of the data frame using only these values:

```
df_new = df[df['column'] is in value_list] # pseudo code
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you John. That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `isin` operation.

```
In [60]: df[df['column'].isin(value_list)]
Out[60]:
   column    x
0       1    3
1       4    6
2       5    8
3       6   19
6      54  102
```

Also, you can use `query` like

```
In [63]: df.query('column in @value_list')
Out[63]:
   column    x
0       1    3
1       4    6
2       5    8
3       6   19
6      54  102
```

Comment: Thank You John Galt

Answer (score 1):

You missed a for loop :

```
df_new = [df[elem]['column'] for elem in df if df[elem]['column'] in value_list]
```

Comment: but I got this error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Can you add to your post a print of your df variable ?

Comment: John's answer was what I was looking for, but thank you iFlo.